# How to pass multiple variables/arguments in a template tag while reverse mapping

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model let say Employee which has fields such as name, joined_date, emp_id, designation.

I have created a search form which takes 'from_date' and 'to_date' in a post calls then I get all employees based on these two dates by using the filter.
Once I come to the employee's page. I have a 'Junior' and 'Senior' tab, once the user clicks on any of these tabs it should again filter with the designation (filter on date range and designation).

I have tried with a couple of things, but it does not work. Please suggest.

```
url:
path('search/', view.search, name="search"),
path('employees/', view.get_employees, name="employees"),
re_path(r'^employees/senior/(?P<from_created>)/(?P<to_created>)/$', view.get_employees, name="senior_employees"),

model:
class Employee(models.Model):
    name
    joined_date
    emp_id
    designation

view:
employees = Employee.objects.filter(joined_date__range=(from_created, to_created), designation="senior")

html template:
<a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'employee:senior_employees' 'from_created' 'to_created' %}" role="tab">Senior</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can pass any number of argument in template tag with reverse mapping and you don't need to reperate it through comma and you don't need to enclosed with quotes as well, just seperate them by a space.

eg:

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'employee:senior_employees' from_created to_created %}" role="tab">Senior</a>
```